# How does the Twilio website work?

Tags: twilio

There is [a good pitch from Twilio here](http://www.avc.com/a_vc/2010/08/how-to-pitch-a-product.html).

I just don't get how they can do that with a website. How can you control a land line with a web browser?

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237364/technology-behind-twilio

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: magic butterflies.

Longer answer: Twilio isn't actually controlling a phone line directly from the browser. There are a few layers between the browser and your phone. For outbound calls it works something like this:

- Web Browser makes requests to...
- Back-end server technology (like PHP/ASP.NET/Rails/etc) makes requests to...
- Twilio REST API which dispatches...
- Magic butterflies to connect the call to...
- The person being called using...
- A URL you specify to direct the call using simple [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml)/XML

For inbound calls, it works pretty much in reverse:

- A caller is connected to...
- Magic butterflies which do their thing and make...
- A HTTP POST request made to the a URL you specify using a...
- Back-end server technology that returns TwiML/XML back to Twilio
- Magic butterflies handle translating TwiML into actions sent back to the caller

In each case, the magic butterflies represent a scalable cloud communications infrastructure that handles all the complicated telephony stuff required to send/receive calls and text messages so that you don't have to worry about anything beyond GET, POST and XML, the stuff you're used to working with every day as a web developer.

[Overview of How Twilio Works for voice calls](http://www.twilio.com/how-twilio-works)

[Sending/Receiving SMS with Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms)

If you have any other questions about how it works, let me know. I work at Twilio :)

Comment: Darn John, you gave away too much information.  Now an army of Indian programmers will be trying to duplicate the magic butterflies.  And asking SO how to duplicate every single wing scale.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had already figured most of it but I was rather interested in the magic butterflies part =)

Comment: Some the details are covered here: http://www.slideshare.net/twilio/twilio-voice-applications-with-amazon-aws-s3-and-ec2-presentation

Comment: Here's some more recent details as well http://www.twilio.com/engineering/2011/10/03/scaling-twilio/

Comment: Hi,Can you put the sample working php code of twilio API plz? I have tried many time that API to send sms as paid member.But not worked atleast one. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: hello I do have a problem I am using twilio ...it works well in my browser in laptop ...but when I open my app on the smartphone it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better link to the **[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/)** web site.

They use their website to sell the service.

They use **[voice over internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voip)** (VOIP) hardware or software to deliver their service.

Comment: hello I do have a problem I am using twilio ...it works well in my browser in laptop ...but when I open my app on the smartphone it doesn't work